# Php Sum with PDO Function with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

New to PDO ... i am trying to get sum but getting error here is my code

```
function test_score_month($student_id){
    global $host, $dbname, $user, $pass;

    $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
    $STH = $DBH->query("SELECT SUM(score), SUM(score_from) FROM school_test_report
    WHERE 
     school_test_report.test_date >= last_march() and school_test_report.test_date <= march()" );
    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
    return $STH;
}
```

out put is

```
$student_id = test_score_month($name);
echo $student_id['SUM(score)'];
```

but getting error

```
Call to a member function setFetchMode() on a non-object in
```

i have tryed

```
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

but still same error

Comment: Does `$STH` have error info? http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php

Comment: This is why PDO should be configured to throw exceptions on errors. Your query fails to be executed (because of `WHERE AND`), but you don't check the return value.

Comment: sorry ad was typing mistake still getting that error without AND

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have syntax error in your query:

```
WHERE 
    and
```

also are you sure that you have `march()` and `last_march()` functions in your DB ?

[+] Always check for errors after querying database:

```
if($STH){
 // do your stuff
}else{
 die($DBH->errorInfo()); // see the error
}
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: sorry and was typing mistake still getting that error without AND

Comment: now i am trying to modify my script and still getting error  `SELECT SUM(score), SUM(score_from) FROM school_test_report
 WHERE student_id='$student_id'` keeping it simple now i am getting output error `$student_id = test_score_month($name);
echo $student_id['SUM(score)'];`   Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array

Comment: @Harinder: Are you doing `$STH->fetch()`?